# Update/filter table content with checkboxes using Flask

Tags: python, forms, flask, jinja2, pythonanywhere

I have created a web app on pythonanywhere, in which I have displayed a dynamic table using flask (jinja2 templating). However, I am not able to update the table by clicking checkboxes.

[the table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/53PoY.png)

If I want to filter this table (let's say I want to display only Turnips and Peas), nothing happens. If I run the program on my localhost, it works completely fine and updates the table after checking the boxes and sending the form. I know I have to update my app.py to somehow re-route the page, but I am not able to figure it out for this particular application. I have tried numerous things using requests and different routes, without success so far.

My HTML template code:

```
<!-- create checkboxes to let the users chose the crop type -->
<form action="" method="get">
    <input type="checkbox" name="field" value="PEAS">Peas</input>
    <input type="checkbox" name="field" value="OIL">Oil Seed Rape</input>
    <input type="checkbox" name="field" value="POTATO">Potatoes</input>
    <input type="checkbox" name="field" value="STRAW">Strawberries</input>
    <input type="checkbox" name="field" value="TURNIPS">Turnips</input>
  <input class="smallButton" type="submit" value="Go!">

</table>
```

and my app.py:

```
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def print_html():
    inpFields = fieldsHtml()
    return render_template('fieldsTemp.html', fields=inpFields)
...
...
  # get the form entry from "fields.html" and assign the elements to a list, then to a string and add it to the SQL statement
    form = cgi.FieldStorage()
    field = form.getlist('field')
    input = "%' OR CROPS.NAME LIKE '%".join(field)

    conn = mysql.connector.connect(
        host= "xxxx.mysql.pythonanywhere-services.com", user="xxxx", password="xxxx", db="xxxx$fieldsFinds")
    c = conn.cursor()
    # c.execute("USE fieldsFinds")
    c.execute(
        f"SELECT * FROM FIELDS JOIN CROPS ON FIELDS.CROP = CROPS.CROP WHERE CROPS.NAME LIKE '%{input}%'")
```

Note that the second part of the code is within the fieldsHtml() function, which I assign to the render_template.

Many thanks in advance for any inputs.

Answer (score 0):

You have a return statement as the second line in print_html, so nothing after that is executed.